# hibernate error: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()Ljava/sql/Connection;

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly

Am deploying a webservice with hibernate on wildfly 10.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.declercq.reportbuilderback</groupId>
    <artifactId>reportbuilderback</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
            tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
                for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
                stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
                from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-resteasy</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
            of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
            as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
            in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
            JBoss WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

        <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
            typesafe criteria queries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
            annotations are incorrectly used. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>







    </profiles>
</project>
```

My UserDao:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        System.out.println("0");
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        System.out.println("0,5");
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<User> allUsers=null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("1");

            /**CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
            criteria.from(User.class);

            allUsers = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
            */
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
            allUsers = (List<User>)criteria.list();
            System.out.println("2");

            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("3");
            return allUsers;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e){
            if(tx != null){
                tx.rollback();
                System.out.println("4");
            }
            return allUsers;
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
            System.out.println("5");

        }
    }
```

My webservice calling this DAO:

```
@GET
    @Path("/all")
    public List<User> listAll() {
        System.out.println("Here");
        final List<User> users = new UserDao().getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("Here 2");
        return users;
    }
```

My server output:

```
10:16:53,980 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices.RestApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
10:16:54,097 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /reportbuilderback
10:16:54,158 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "reportbuilderback.war" (runtime-name : "reportbuilderback.war")
10:16:54,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
10:16:54,394 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:16:54,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 14662ms - Started 422 of 670 services (404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
10:17:02,761 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Here
10:17:02,762 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 0
10:17:03,138 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (default task-3) HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
10:17:03,140 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (default task-3) HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/reportbuilderwebservices]
10:17:03,140 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (default task-3) HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=reportbuilderwebservices, password=****}
10:17:03,141 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (default task-3) HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
10:17:03,141 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (default task-3) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
10:17:03,162 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
10:17:03,340 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (default task-3) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10:17:03,349 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (default task-3) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@2f2d8520
10:17:03,352 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (default task-3) Envers integration enabled? : true
10:17:03,363 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (default task-3) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
10:17:03,452 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 0,5
10:17:03,452 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 1
10:17:03,459 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 2
10:17:03,460 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 3
10:17:03,462 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /reportbuilderback/rest/users/all: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()Ljava/sql/Connection;
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()Ljava/sql/Connection;
    at org.declercq.reportbuilderback.dao.UserDao.getAllUsers(UserDao.java:76)
    at org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices.UserWebService.listAll(UserWebService.java:52)
    at org.declercq.reportbuilderback.webservices.UserWebService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.listAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
    ... 43 more
```

Claiming that:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.close()Ljava/sql/Connection;
    at org.declercq.reportbuilderback.dao.UserDao.getAllUsers(UserDao.java:76)
```

I'm not using Spring by the way for this.
Could someone give me some insight here?
I'm guessing it must be some conflict with 2 hibernate libraries of different versions or something like that, but I'm not really sure where it is...

UPDATE: I'm still not getting this to work.
Below my output from maven dependency tree:

```
mvn dependency:tree 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building librarysoftbackend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ librarysoftbackend ---
[INFO] org.declercq.librarysoftbackend:librarysoftbackend:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:3.0.10.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.4.GA:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:jar:4.3.5.Final:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:provided
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:jar:5.1.3.Final:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.3:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.7.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:provided
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:async-http-servlet-3.0:jar:3.0.10.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.0.10.Final:provided
[INFO] \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.10.Final:provided
[INFO]    +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:provided
[INFO]    +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.6:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.5:provided
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO]    |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:provided
[INFO]    +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO]    \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.965 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-11T13:40:28+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/174M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyone any idea?

Comment: yeah..you got that. print the dependancy tree for your **pom.xml**. There are conflicting hibernate jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You import hibernate-core via jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate (version 4.3.7) and also via

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But WildFly 10 provides Hibernate 5.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I just noticed it a few minutes before you replied, finally saw it: I was using the wrong BOM in my pom.xml in <dependencymanagement> section. Fixed now, thanks!